# oauth2 server creation Nodejs

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, oauth2orize

I'm trying to implement an OAUTH2 server in nodeJS, which allows client app to login users using my website(like login with google).
I tried using oauth2orise(https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth2orize) and referred few links:-

https://hnryjms.io/2014/07/oauth2/
http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/07/02/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-oauth2-server/ 
but still I'm not being able to understand how methods are getting invoked and how exactly I should Implement the flow. 
So if anyone could explain how to implement that would be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://login.shoppre.com/signin?client_id=identity using it in production with full implementation, https://identity.shoppre.com/guide/nodejs-oauth-implementation.html https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shoppre/oauth2-server